# `pytest`: Downloading a test file once, and using it for multiple tests

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fixtures

I am using `pytest` to run test case for a package I am developing. The tests use a small image file that I have saved as a github asset. The code below works just fine, but I think that `pytest` is downloading the image each time it runs a new test and that takes unnecessary time and resources. I was trying to figure out how I can download the file once, and then share it across test cases

Here is some sample code.

```
# -- in conftest.py --
import sys
import pytest
import os
import shutil
import requests

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def small_image(tmpdir):
    url = 'https://github.com/.../sample_image_small.tif'

    r = requests.get(url)

    with open(os.path.join(str(tmpdir), 'sample_image_small.tif'), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)

    return os.path.join(str(tmpdir), 'sample_image_small.tif')
```

Then here are some very simple test cases that should be able to share the same image.

```
# -- test_package.py --
import pytest
import os

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('small_image')


def test_ispath(small_image, compression):

    assert os.path.exists(small_image)

def test_isfile(small_image, compression):

    assert os.path.isfile(small_image)
```

Now I believe that `pytest` will try and isolate each test by itself and so that is what causes the repeated downloads of files. I tried to set the `@pytest.fixture(scope="module")` instead of `function` but that was generating strange errors:

```
ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the 'function' scoped fixture 'tmpdir' with a 'module' scoped request object, involved factories
```

Is there a better way to setup the tests so that I don't keep download the file over and over?

Comment: Even worse, you can't run your tests without a connection to Github. If you need that file for your tests, make it part of your tests, i.e. store it locally! Is there perhaps some other reason for not doing that which you haven't told us about yet?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Oh there were a couple of reasons. First, the testing file is 8mb and there is no reason why a user of the package would need to download that file unless he/she were testing. So no need to make the package bigger if I add additional test images. Second, dealing with relative or absolute paths in packages is challenging because different platforms can alter the organization of the folders. So it seems a lot more portable and maintainable to just download the test images when needed.

Answer (score 6):

First, a note beforehand: a better alternative to the old `tmpdir`/`tmpdir_factory` fixtures pair is `tmp_path`/`tmp_path_factory` which deals with `pathlib` objects instead of the deprecated `py.path`, see [Temporary directories and files](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/tmpdir.html#temporary-directories-and-files).

Second, if you want to handle files session-scoped (or module-scoped), `tmp*_factory` fixtures are meant for that. Example:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def small_image(tmp_path_factory):
    img = tmp_path_factory.getbasetemp() / 'sample_image_small.tif'
    img.write_bytes(b'spam')
    return img
```

The `sample_image_small.tif` will now be written once per test run.

---

Of course, there's nothing wrong with using `tempfile` as suggested by @MrBean Bremen in his answer, this is just an alternative doing the same, but using only  standard `pytest` fixtures.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same code, just handle the tempfile yourself instead of using the `tmpdir` fixture (which cannot be used in module-scoped fixtures):

```py
import os
import tempfile
import pytest
import requests

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def small_image():
    url = 'https://github.com/.../sample_image_small.tif'

    r = requests.get(url)
    f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False):
    f.write(f.content)
    yield f.name
    os.remove(f.name)
```

This will create the file, return the file name, and delete the file after the tests are finished.

*EDIT:*
The answer by @hoefling shows a more standard way to do this, I'll leave this one for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will give it a shot :).